# Why don't mosquitoes target the visible blood vessels under the skin?

Tags: ecology, parasitology

We can see numerous veins under our skin. Why don't mosquitoes suck blood from those vessels?

Why don't they use better option?

Comment: This is unclear. Where do you think mosquitos get their blood from?

Comment: they suck only plane skin but not the skin which is elevated by large vessels underneath it. Large vessels will definitely provide more blood.

Comment: Mosquitos suck blood from small capillaries. And they don't suck very much, only about 5 µl.

Comment: Why not from large vessels?

Comment: Is there a reason why you assume mosquitoes even have the ability to identify and attribute meaning to larger blood vessels that subsequently elevate skin? Also, why do you think that accessing larger blood vessels is "better", if the mosquito can obtain the same amount of blood from other, smaller vessels? Perhaps it's in fact easier for the mosquito to go undetected by accessing smaller blood vessels, due to the possibility of increased skin sensativity in the region of larger blood vessels. This is of course, just speculation/conjucture.

Comment: large blood vessels have more pressure so in less time mosquito can suck the required amount of blood and would also require less energy, since blood will ooze out unlike capillaries where the mosquito might have to suck actively.

Comment: @Test_1 I think you are assuming that the mosquito doesn't already experience the maximum throughput of blood from smaller blood vessels when harvesting. Conversly, it could be that the higher pressure from larger vessels is too strong for the mosquito, so they tend to harvest from smaller vessels. Lastly, I would like to assert that *beggers can't be choosers*, and I'm sure that (most all) mosquitoes will take blood wherever they can get it, just like with most other living (surviving) organisms behave when attempting to gather environmental resources (for whatever reason).

Comment: The smart mosquitoes that have been through a phlebotomy course do go after the large veins closest to the surface. However, at times, they mistake an artery for a vein, and blow themselves up. It's a nasty affair. Most mosquitoes who've witnessed this just stick with dermal capillaries.

Comment: @anongoodnurse What a sense of humour!

Comment: @anongoodnurse how do these mosquito pass on this information to next generation and the other mosquitoes of existing generation?( just for humour)

Comment: Related: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BF_Ua1xCAAAKMYf.jpg :)

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason that you can drink from a drinking fountain, but not a fire hose :-)

Answer (score 4):

For a mosquito, there is really no benefit to targeting those visible blood vessels. Mosquitoes take only a small amount of blood, and their proboscis is going to be a limiting factor anyways.

However, mosquitoes also aren't just blinding sticking their proboscis into the extracellular space. They actually do target individual vessels, and scientists have actually been able to video the process. Capillaries are good targets because they are found in all the tissues, so the mosquito doesn't need to find a surface vein.

See the videos with the original paper here: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0050464 (in the "Supporting information" section)

There are also versions on YouTube, like here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbXSPacvuak

Choumet, V., Attout, T., Chartier, L., Khun, H., Sautereau, J., Robbe-Vincent, A., ... & Bain, O. (2012). Visualizing non infectious and infectious Anopheles gambiae blood feedings in naive and saliva-immunized mice. PLoS One, 7(12), e50464.

Comment: In the video , the mosquito is squeezing blood from capillaries so hard that capillary is collapsed, then why do you think that proboscis is a limiting factor?